# Building a nondeterministic monad transformer in haskell

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, non-deterministic, monadplus

I would like to build a nondeterministic monad transformer in haskell that, I believe, behaves differently from ListT and from the alternative ListT proposed at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right. The first of these associates a monad with a list of items; the second associates a monad with individual items but has the property that monadic actions in given element influence monadic elements in subsequent slots of the list. The goal is to build a monad transformer of the form

```
data Amb m a = Cons (m a) (Amb m a) | Empty
```

so that every element of the list has its own monad associated with it and that successive elements have independent monads. At the end of this post I have a little demonstration of the kind of behavior this monad should give. If you know how to get some variant of ListT to give this behavior, that would be helpful too.

Below is my attempt. It is incomplete because the `unpack` function is undefined. How can I define it? Here's one incomplete attempt at defining it, but it doesn't take care of the case when the monad m contains an `Empty` Amb list:

```
unpack :: (Monad m) => m (Amb m a) -> Amb m a                                                                                                                 
unpack m = let first = join $ do (Cons x ys) <- m                                                                                                             
                                 return x                                                                                                                     
               rest =  do (Cons x ys) <- m                                                                                                                    
                          return ys                                                                                                                           
           in Cons first (unpack rest)
```

**Full (incomplete) code:**

```
import Prelude hiding  (map, concat)                                                                                                                          
import Control.Monad                                                                                                                                          
import Control.Monad.Trans       

data Amb m a = Cons (m a) (Amb m a) | Empty                                                                                                                   

infixr 4 <:>                                                                                                                                                  
(<:>) = Cons                                                                                                                                                  

map :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Amb m a -> Amb m b                                                                                                              
map f (Cons m xs) = Cons y (map f xs)                                                                                                                         
    where y = do a <- m                                                                                                                                       
                 return $ f a                                                                                                                                 
map f Empty = Empty                                                                                                                                           

unpack :: m (Amb m a) -> Amb m a                                                                                                                              
unpack m = undefined                                                                                                                                          


concat :: (Monad m) => Amb m (Amb m a) -> Amb m a                                                                                                             
concat (Cons m xs)  = (unpack m) `mplus` (concat xs)                                                                                                          
concat  Empty = Empty                                                                                                                                         

instance Monad m => Monad (Amb m) where                                                                                                                       
    return x = Cons (return x) Empty                                                                                                                          
    xs >>= f = let yss = map f xs                                                                                                                             
               in concat yss                                                                                                                                  

instance Monad m => MonadPlus (Amb m) where                                                                                                                   
    mzero = Empty                                                                                                                                             
    (Cons m xs) `mplus` ys = Cons m (xs `mplus` ys)                                                                                                           
    Empty `mplus` ys = ys                                                                                                                                     

instance MonadTrans Amb where                                                                                                                                 
    lift m = Cons m Empty
```

**Examples of desired behavior**

Here, the base monad is `State Int`

```
instance Show a => Show (Amb (State Int) a) where                                                                                                             
    show m = (show .  toList) m                                                                                                                               


toList :: Amb (State Int) a -> [a]                                                                                                                            
toList Empty = []                                                                                                                                             
toList (n `Cons` xs) = (runState n 0 : toList xs)                                                                                                             


x = (list $ incr) >> (incr <:> incr <:> Empty)                                                                                                                
y = (list $ incr) >> (incr <:> (incr >> incr) <:> Empty)                                                                                                      

main = do                                                                                                                                                     
  putStr $ show x -- | should be [2, 2]                                                                                                                       
  putStr $ show y -- | should be [2, 3]
```

Thanks.

**Update: An example of why LogicT doesn't do what I want.**

Here's what LogicT does on the simple example above:

```
import Control.Monad                                                                                                                                          
import Control.Monad.Logic                                                                                                                                    
import Control.Monad.State                                                                                                                                    

type LogicState = LogicT (State Int)                                                                                                                          


incr :: State Int Int                                                                                                                                         
incr = do i <- get                                                                                                                                            
          put (i + 1)                                                                                                                                         
          i' <- get                                                                                                                                           
          return i'                                                                                                                                           

incr' = lift incr                                                                                                                                             
y =  incr' >> (incr' `mplus` incr')                                                                                                                           

main = do                                                                                                                                                     
  putStrLn $ show (fst $ runState (observeAllT y) 0)   -- | returns [2,3], not [2,2]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [logict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict)?

Comment: Just a note, in your incomplete `unpack`, `first = do { (Cons x _) <- m; x }`. You don't need the extra layer of `join` and `return`.

Comment: @DanielWagner On your suggestion I looked at logict and added an example at the end of the post showing why I think logict doesn't do what I want.

Comment: @Eyal I'm glad you added the examples. `StateT` already does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just use `StateT`. For example:

```
import Control.Monad.State

incr = modify (+1)
sample1 = incr `mplus` incr
sample2 = incr `mplus` (incr >> incr)

monomorphicExecStateT :: StateT Int [] a -> Int -> [Int]
monomorphicExecStateT = execStateT

main = do
    print (monomorphicExecStateT sample1 0) -- [1, 1]
    print (monomorphicExecStateT sample2 0) -- [1, 2]
```

Comment: My example asks for the behavior of ``incr >> (incr `mplus` incr)`` not ``incr `mplus` (incr >> incr)``. The mystery is how to "distribute" the effect of the external `incr` across the internal ones.

Comment: @Eyal Just try it and see. `print (monomorphicExecStateT (incr >> sample1) 0)` prints `[2,2]`, just like you asked for. The initial `incr >>` isn't actually interesting in your question -- only the `mplus` behavior is interesting and hard. As for you saying you don't ask for `incr \`mplus\` (incr >> incr)`, well, just look at the definition of `y` in your sample code. =)

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. Maybe it's as simple as you suggest. In my actual use case, my base monad is not State but is some monad of my own crafting. So that means that rather than transforming my base monad with some monad transformer, I need to develop a monad transformer version of my base monad and transform the list monad with it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in the general case (and a monad transformer should be able to transform any monad). The unpack option you mention is not possible for monads in general - it corresponds to the operation:

```
extract :: (Comonad w) => w a -> a
```

Which is an operation on a comonad (the mathematical dual of a monad).

There are things you can do to 'unpack' it by taking the (m (Amb m a)) and mapping it several times to produce a single (m a) in each case, but this requires you to know in advance (or rather, from outside the monad) how many choices are being created, which you cannot know without some form of extract operation.

The reason that in the second ListT the tail of the list depends on a monadic action is because we need to perform a monadic action in some cases in order to find out how many choices are being produced (and thus how long the list is).

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's sort of what I anticipated. Can you think of how to implement a solution to this problem? Should I try to define a comonad instance for my base monad, or would you do something different?

Comment: I'm almost finished writing something that I think is as close as you can easily get it - it's basically a free monad. Be with you in a couple of minutes by further comment.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, although I wouldn't suggest using it without someone more expert than me having a look.

https://gist.github.com/4288510

Some of the explanation may have a little more detail than you need, I wasn't sure how familiar with Haskell you are exactly (and I'm not an expert).